# Parse data from a complex dictionary in Python

Tags: json, python-3.x, dataframe, dictionary

I'm brand new to programming and have taken several days trying to solve this problem.  I have the following response from an API that I would like to reformat so I can read it better, and use pieces of the data in future codes.

I'm using the following code

```
import requests  
import pandas  
for item in items: #item is defined previously in the code  
response = request.get(url, parameters={put stuff here}, headers={more stuff here})  
json_response = response.json()  
  print(item)  
 print(json_response)
```

output:

```
item1  
{'series':{'data':[{'keyA':'value1', 'keyB:value2, 'keyC':value3}, {'keyA':'value4', 'keyB:value5, 'keyC':value6}, {'keyA':'value7', 'keyB:value8, 'keyC':value9}]}}  
item2  
{'series':{'data':[{'keyA':'value10', 'keyB:value11, 'keyC':value12}, {'keyA':'value13', 'keyB:value14, 'keyC':value15}, {'keyA':'value16', 'keyB:value17, 'keyC':value18}]}}
```

I'd like to get the output to look like this:

```
item1  
keyA        keyB         keyC  
value1     value2       value3  
value4     value5       value6  
value7     value8       value9  
  
item2  
keyA         keyB          keyC  
value10     value11       value12  
value13     value14       value15  
value16     value17       value18
```

I've tried several pandas and numpy codes, but I can't find anything that works.  Everything I try results in a multitude of errors.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make a dataframe from `item` you can do:

```py
item = {
    "series": {
        "data": [
            {"keyA": "value1", "keyB": "value2", "keyC": "value3"},
            {"keyA": "value4", "keyB": "value5", "keyC": "value6"},
            {"keyA": "value7", "keyB": "value8", "keyC": "value9"},
        ]
    }
}

df = pd.DataFrame(item["series"]["data"])
print(df)
```

Prints:

```
     keyA    keyB    keyC
0  value1  value2  value3
1  value4  value5  value6
2  value7  value8  value9
```

---

With your pseudo-code:

```py
for item in items:
    response = request.get(url, parameters={put stuff here}, headers={more stuff here})  
    json_response = response.json() 

    df = pd.DataFrame(json_response["series"]["data"])
    print(df)
```